# C# Static Property Async Access

Tags: c#, .net

I have a static helper class with static property. The idea is that this static property can change from any async method in my app. I found the problem after start writing unit tests where use this static property as member data. Somehow the data from another tests become to others, somehow the property keep state from previous member data. The test methods are async. How to make new copy or new instance for this helper or property for every test method. Also I think this will be the same problem in production.I want static property to keep his state for each request or test, this means request1 started state and request1 works with only state1, request2 started, request2 works only with state2 and ...

````
```
public static class SharedHelper
{
 public static int SharedProperty { get; set; }
}

 public class MyTests
{
public static TheoryData<int> TestData =>
    new TheoryData<int> { 1, 2, 3 }; // Add more test data as needed

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
public async Task TestMethod(int testData)
{
    // Each test method will have its own testData
    SharedHelper.SharedProperty = testData;

    // Your test logic here

    Assert.Equal(testData, SharedHelper.SharedProperty);
}
}
```
````

Comment: It sounds like a static property isn't the way to go in the first place.  If by "request" you're referring to a web application then what you're describing is more stateless in general, whereas a static property will retain state throughout the application.  And as far as unit testing goes, relying on static values is notoriously difficult.  Can you clarify why you have this static property in the first place and what underlying functionality you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes the reason is that property is used from 3 different validators and each validator can set the part of this property I already tried with AsyncLocal but without any success

Comment: That doesn't at all explain why you need a static property or what functionality you're achieving with it.  Why do these three validators need to share this property?  Why does it need to be static?  What happens if you *don't* use a static property for whatever functionality you're trying to achieve?  Overall the question reads such that you've used a static property for some purpose, but you don't want it to *be* static (shared across threads, difficult to unit test, etc.).  In which case it sounds like you'll want to re-think the implementation in the first place.

Comment: "I want static property to keep his state for each request" then use a store that is per request and not static. If request means some Asp.Net Core thing you might want to look at what scope means and how to get something injected/stored per scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with AsyncLocal, this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

These are fundamental problems with global mutable state. You cannot make "a new copy or new instance for this helper", since there is **only one**. This problem has been known about for many decades.

You say you want to keep track of the state of *multiple requests*. So the solution is to not use a mutable static property. You will instead need to define some type of "context" where property is valid for.

The simplest solution is to just create a class to represent your "context", and implement methods for everything that needs to use this property:

```
public class MyClass{
    private int SharedProperty { get; set; }
    public async Task MyMethod1(){
         ...
    }
    public async Task MyMethod2(){
         ...
    }
}
```

This require each method to coordinate how they use the property. But the property is private, so it is *only* the methods in the class that needs to coordinate. This helps ensure correct behavior of your program, and helps ensure it can be tested. You can also use a [Dependency injection container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) to specify the context, like a "container static" object.

There are also things like [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-8.0) that can be used within the context of an asynchronous method. If you are using ASP.Net you might want to look at HttpContext.Items, but see [session and state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more info. I'm not an asp developer, so my knowledge is limited in this regard.